# hightlight datatable jquery

Tags: php, ajax, datatable

I searched a lot on the internet and have not found the solution to my problem.

Im working with AJAX, PHP and Datatables. 
The pluing works fine. I could display the records in my Datatable.

I want to do that does not work is that when mouse over each row, it "lights" and removing the mouse back to normal.

As far as I managed to find out, what is happening to me is that the event does not detect  row. That is, the code I use is as follows ...

```
    $("#tabla  tbody  tr").each(function(){ 

            $(this).mouseover(function(){                       
               $(this).addClass("ui-state-hover");

              }).mouseout(function(){
                   $(this).removeClass("ui-state-hover");       
               });
    });
```

Html code:

```
         <table id="tabla">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Id</th>
                    <th>Titulo</th>
                    <th>Subtitulo</th>
                    <th>Fecha</th>
                    <th>Acceder</th>
                </tr> 
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
       </table>
```

If I add to the page manually a row, IT WORKS the mouseover
Example:

> ```
>        <table id="tabla">
>             <thead>
>                 <tr>
>                     <th>Id</th>
>                     <th>Titulo</th>
>                     <th>Subtitulo</th>
>                     <th>Fecha</th>
>                     <th>Acceder</th>
>                 </tr> 
>             </thead>
>             <tbody>
>                 <tr >
>                     <td>4</td>
>                     <td>Titulo</td>
>                     <td>Subtitulo</td>
>                     <td>2013-09-11 00:00:00</td>
>                     <td>4</td>
>                 </tr> 
>             </tbody>
>        </table>
> ```

THE PROBLEM is that I DO NOT WORK when the rows are inserted through AJAX function.

AJAX Code:

```
$.ajax({

       url:'./listahistorias_proceso.php',
       type:'post',
       data:{ tag: 'getData'},
       dataType: 'json',
       success: function(data){
                if(data.success){
                    $.each(data, function(index,record){
                        if($.isNumeric(index)){
                            var row = $("<tr />");
                            $("<td />").text(record.idhistoria).appendTo(row);
                            $("<td />").text(record.titulo).appendTo(row);
                            $("<td />").text(record.subtitulo).appendTo(row);
                            $("<td />").text(record.fecha).appendTo(row);
                            $("<td />").text(record.acceder).appendTo(row);                             
                            $("<tr>");
                            row.appendTo('table tbody');
                        }
                     })
                }

                oTable = $('table').dataTable({
                        "bjQueryUI": true,
                        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                        "oLanguage": {
                                    "sLengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ filas por pagina",
                                    "sZeroRecords": "Datos no encontrados",
                                    "sInfo": "Mostrando _START_ a _END_ de _TOTAL_ filas",
                                    "sInfoEmpty": "Sin entradas para mostrar",
                                    "sInfoFiltered": "",
                                    "sSearch": "Buscar",
                                    "sProcessing": "Buscando...",
                                    "sLoadingRecords": "Por favor espere - Cargando...",
                                    "sEmptyTable": "No se obtuvieron datos",
                                    "oPaginate": {
                                                "sFirst": "Primera",
                                                "sPrevious": "Anterior",
                                                "sNext": "Siguiente",
                                                "sLast": "Ultima"
                                              }

                                    },
                        "aoColumns":[
                                     {'sname':'id', 'sType':'numeric', 'bVisible':true},
                                     {'sName':'Titulo', 'sType':'string','bVisible':true},
                                     {'sName':'Subtitulo', 'sType':'string','bVisible':true},
                                     {'sName':'Fecha', 'sType':'date','bVisible':true},
                                     {'sName':'Acceder', 'sType':'numeric','bVisible':true}
                                     ],
                        "oTableTools": {
                                   "sRowSelect": "single",                      
                                   "fnRowSelected": function( node ) {
                                     alert("Clicked");
                                       }
                        } 
                 })


        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){ 
                alert("error ==>" + jqXHR.responseText);
                alert("error ==>" + jqXHR.textStatus);
                alert("excepcion ==>" + errorThrown); 

        }

}); //ajax
```

Note:
I tied with .live(), .on(), .click() and doesn't work.

Again, I think the problem is that it doesn't detect rows inserted by ajax.

From already thank you very much. I hope I was clear.
I await your comments.

Thank you again.
Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is exactly that the elements don't exist when your jQuery is initially run.  Now you said you had used `on()` previously, but you did not include that code.  I am just assuming you implemented it incorrectly (i.e. perhaps didn't use delegated events approach). It should look something like this:

```
$('#tabla tbody').on('mouseenter', 'tr', function() {
    $(this).addClass("ui-state-hover");
});
$('#tabla tbody').on('mouseleave', 'tr', function() {
    $(this).removeClass("ui-state-hover");
});
```

`on()` allows you to bind event handlers to elements that do not yet exist in the DOM. In this case you are attaching an event handler to `#tabla tbody` (which must exist on initial document load). So as any events from descendant elements of `#tabla tbody` occur, they bubble up to the `on()` event handler tied to `#tabla tbody`, which then can determine based on the event type (`mouseenter/mouseleave` in this case), and based on whether the target element meets the filtering criteria (in this case the element must be a `tr` underneath `#tabla tbody`), then the handler will be run on that target element.

Here is documentation: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Note that I specified mouseenter/mouseleave instead of mouseover/mouseout. This is because this is probably the behavior you actually want rather than having these events fired when child elements (i.e. `td`'s) are also hovered, which is what would happen for mouseover/mouseout.